# ngCordova in Angular JS Web Application

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am not an expert in Angular and have recently started learning it, I am trying to create a responsive form in an AngularJS WEB APPLICATION which will let me upload a file or a photo from a mobile browser (not mobile app). Before I upload anything through my mobile browser, I should check the native settings of my mobile device (not browser settings but the settings of my mobile device). 
To achieve this I am using ngCordova with it's wrapper $cordovaFileTransfer. I have a normal project in Eclipse and I have included below files in my index page(I have stored these files locally in my project).

- cordova.js
- file.js
- fileTransfer.js
- ng-cordova.js
- ng-cordova.min.js

Since I am using Eclipse, I tried to install THyM plugin however it wouldn't install in my work space. Below is my controller code.

```
angular.module('app').controller(
    'CordovaCtrl',
    function($scope, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(
                $cordovaFileTransfer) {
            alert("Inside the Cordova Controller - deviceready");
            var fileToUpload = "";
            var options = {

                fileKey : "sendFile",
                fileName : "angularJSFileToUpload",
                chunkedMode : false,
                mimeType : "text/plain"

            };
            var server = "C:/Dev/Angular file receiver";// Temporary path
            var targetPath = "C:/Dev/Angular file sender";// Temporary path
            $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, targetPath, options).then(
                    function() {
                        alert("Success");
                    }, function(err) {
                        alert("Error");
                    });

        }, false)
    });
```

I understand that all plugin calls should be wrapped in the `"deviceready"` event. Whenever I run my project I get below error on the browser console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/fileupload/cordova/cordova_plugins.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Event> has no method 'upload' app.js:46
```

I am not sure where the cordova_plugins.js gets fetched from. I had read on some forum that it gets generated at run time (I might be wrong). 
Does anyone have any idea about what’s going wrong here? I reckon I am missing something on the configuration part. Is it even possible to use ngCordova in a web application since supposedly its meant for mobile development?

Answer (score 0):

### Try code below

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('CordovaCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        alert("Inside the Cordova Controller - deviceready");
        var fileToUpload = "img.png";
        var options = {
            fileKey : "sendFile",
            fileName : "angularJSFileToUpload",
            chunkedMode : false,
            mimeType : "text/plain"

        };
        var server = "C:/Dev/Angular file receiver";// Temporary path
        var targetPath = "C:/Dev/Angular file sender";// Temporary path

        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, targetPath, options)
        .then(function(result) {
                    alert("Success");
                }, function(err) {
                    alert("Error");
                }, function(progress){
                 alert("In Progress");
                });
    }, false)
});
```

Comment: Please post explanations with your code, not just large blocks of code.